# Calculation on vTiger field before save handler

Tags: php, vtiger

I am currently working on a custom module in vTiger 6.5, I want to populate a field based on the calculation of two others. Here is what I have tried below. I am looking to do this without the use of workflows.

```
    $units = $entityData->get('numberofunits');
                $value = $entityData->get('unitvalue');
$entitydata->set('currentamount',$units * $value);
                }
```

Im not sure if it is a syntax problem or if I am heading in the wrong direction.

Thanks

Comment: I have also tried to put the calculation into a variable and tired `$entitydata->set('currentamount',$calculation);` and I have echo'd the variable with success.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do a realtime calculation, why don't you do it on javascript side ?

You can add this function your custom Edit.js file:

```
calculate_amount: function (){
    var units = $("input[name='numberofunits']");
    var value = $("input[name='unitvalue']");

    $(units, value).on('keyup', function(){
        if (units.val() != '' && value.val() != ''){
              var currentamount = units.val() * value.val();
              $("input[name='currentamount']").val(currentamount);
        }
    });
}
```

The currentamount field will be populate with the result of the units and value multiplication.